# MPAndroidChart. In BarChart i have duplicate background lines

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm created BarChart using MPAndroidChart and remove right YAxis labels by follow code:
`mBarChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);`

after this, my background lines become duplicated

Before:

[image]

Here is what I have now:

[image]

My code:

```
//barChart
    mBarChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    mBarChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);

    mBarChart.setDescription("");

    // if more than 60 entries are displayed in the chart, no values will be
    // drawn
    mBarChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(60);

    // scaling can now only be done on x- and y-axis separately
    mBarChart.setPinchZoom(true);

    // draw shadows for each bar that show the maximum value
     mBarChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    mBarChart.animateY(2000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInQuart);

    // mChart.setDrawXLabels(false);

    mBarChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
     //mBarChart.setDrawYLabels(false);



    XAxis xAxis = mBarChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setTypeface(tf);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels(2);

    ValueFormatter custom = new MyValueFormatter();

    YAxis leftAxis = mBarChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setTypeface(tf);
    leftAxis.setLabelCount(6);
    leftAxis.setValueFormatter(custom);
    leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
    leftAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);


    mBarChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
    /*YAxis rightAxis = mBarChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    rightAxis.setTypeface(tf);
    rightAxis.setLabelCount(8);
    rightAxis.setValueFormatter(custom);
    rightAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);*/

    Legend legend = mBarChart.getLegend();
    legend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_LEFT);
    legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE);
    legend.setFormSize(9f);
    legend.setTextSize(11f);
    legend.setXEntrySpace(4f);
    /* legend.setExtra(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS, new String[] { "abc",
     "def", "ghj", "ikl", "mno" });
     legend.setCustom(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS, new String[] { "abc",
     "def", "ghj", "ikl", "mno" });*/

    setDataToBarChart(mParties.size(), 50);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that the right axis is not disabled, but only it's labels are hidden, and you have different settings (the top-space, typeface and label count) that cause the lines to be in different places.

**To prevent this from happening**, call `rightAxis.setEnabled(false)`. This will disable the whole axis and no longer cause your issue.

It's all in the [**documentation**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis).

Comment: Yest, it helps) Thank you for your library and sory for my inattention)